# Highlights (Mouseover, mouseout, click) in WFS layer

Tags: leaflet, wfs, mapserver

I need to highlight on click of objects in a layer and popups with attributions provided by a WFS.

I got the whole layer highlight on mouseover/mouseout, but I need this on click and only one object to highlight, not whole layer. Like this:[image: figure showing highlight of feature]

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    html, body, #map {
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }    
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/leaflet-wfst.src.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var map = L.map('map').setView([50, 50], 3);
  
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map); 

  var defaultStyle = {
            color: "#2262CC",
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 0.6,
            fillOpacity: 0.1,
            fillColor: "#2262CC",
            fillColor: 'transparent'
        };
  var highlightStyle = {
            color: 'red', 
            weight: 5,
            opacity: 0.6,
            fillOpacity: 0.65,
            fillColor: 'red',
            fillColor: 'transparent'
        };

  var polygons = new L.WFS({
    version: '1.1.0',
    url: 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=E:/data/test/test.map',
    request: 'GetFeature',
    showExisting:   true,
    typeNS: 'ms',
    typeName: 'Regions',
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
    geometryField: 'msGeometry',
    style: defaultStyle
    });

  map.addLayer(polygons);
      
  var popup = L.popup();

  polygons.on('click', function (event) {
    popup
      .setLatLng(event.latlng)
      .setContent(event.layer.getProperty('NAME') + '<br/>' + event.layer.getProperty('ADM3_NAME'))
      .openOn(map);
  });

  polygons.on('mouseover', function (e) {
      var layer = e.target;
      layer.setStyle(highlightStyle);
  });

  polygons.on('mouseout', function (e) { 
      var layer = e.target;
      layer.setStyle(defaultStyle);
  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.map

```
MAP
NAME        "WFS"
STATUS      ON  
FONTSET         "E:/data/fonts/fonts.list"
EXTENT          -180 -90 180 90
SIZE            1600 700
IMAGECOLOR      255 255 255
SHAPEPATH       "E:/data/test/shp/" 
WEB
 IMAGEPATH    "E:/tiles/ms_tmp/"
 IMAGEURL     "/ms_tmp/"
  METADATA
    "wfs_title"                     "Regions"
    "wfs_abstract"                  "Regions"
    "wfs_onlineresource"            "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=E:/data/test/test.map&"
    "wfs_srs"                       "EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857"
    "wfs_enable_request"            "*"
  END
END

PROJECTION
  "init=epsg:3857"
END 

LAYER
  NAME "Regions"
  DATA "Regions.shp"
  STATUS ON
  TYPE POLYGON    
  CLASS
    NAME "Regions"
        STYLE
            COLOR 255 128 128
            OUTLINECOLOR 255 0 0
        END
  END          
  METADATA
    "wfs_title"                 "Regions"
    "wfs_abstract"              "Regions"
    "wfs_onlineresource"            "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=E:/data/test/test.map&"        
    "wfs_enable_request"            "*"
    "gml_include_items"             "all"
    "gml_featureid"                 "fid"
  END
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:4326"
    END       
END
END
```

I'm using the plugin https://github.com/Flexberry/Leaflet-WFST
I tried to apply example from Leaflet tutorial https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/, but I don't know how to apply it in my code. It's really hard for me now.

DescribeFeatureType

```
<schema xmlns:ms="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" targetNamespace="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="0.1">
<import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>
<element name="Regions" type="ms:RegionsType" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature"/>
<complexType name="RegionsType">
<complexContent>
<extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
<sequence>
<element name="msGeometry" type="gml:GeometryPropertyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
<element name="NAME" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
<element name="ADM3_NAME" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
<element name="fid" minOccurs="0" type="string"/>
</sequence>
</extension>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
</schema>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get your test.map OGC package?

Comment: You mean content of test.map? added.

Comment: or possibly the output from a DescribeFeatureType request like:  `http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=E:/data/test/test.map&version=1.1.0&service=WFS&request=DescribeFeatureType&typename=ms:Regions&`

Comment: DescribeFeatureType added.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you should `resetStyle` when you write the function for `mouseout`. I hope it work!